# Prove no odd number can be abundant.

Tags: problem-solving, divisor-sum

A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of $28$ would be $1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28$, which means that $28$ is a perfect number.

A number $n$ is called abundant if this sum exceeds $n$.

Suppose $n$ was odd. Then $\frac{n}{2}$ is not a divisor, since $\frac{n}{2}$ is not an integer.

The only way I can see it being abundant is if $\frac{n}{3}$ was an integer, and then we got proper divisors below $\frac{n}{3}$ that summed up to be greater than $\frac{2n}{3}$.

Take a look, for example, at the first 1000 abundant numbers:

```
12      18      20      24      30      36      40      42      48      54
56      60      66      70      72      78      80      84      88      90
96      100     102     104     108     112     114     120     126     132
138     140     144     150     156     160     162     168     174     176
180     186     192     196     198     200     204     208     210     216
220     222     224     228     234     240     246     252     258     260
264     270     272     276     280     282     288     294     300     304
306     308     312     318     320     324     330     336     340     342
348     350     352     354     360     364     366     368     372     378
380     384     390     392     396     400     402     408     414     416
420     426     432     438     440     444     448     450     456     460
462     464     468     474     476     480     486     490     492     498
500     504     510     516     520     522     528     532     534     540
544     546     550     552     558     560     564     570     572     576
580     582     588     594     600     606     608     612     616     618
620     624     630     636     640     642     644     648     650     654
660     666     672     678     680     684     690     696     700     702
704     708     714     720     726     728     732     736     738     740
744     748     750     756     760     762     768     770     774     780
784     786     792     798     800     804     810     812     816     820
822     828     832     834     836     840     846     852     858     860
864     868     870     876     880     882     888     894     896     900
906     910     912     918     920     924     928     930     936     940
942     945     948     952     954     960     966     968     972     978
980     984     990     992     996     1000
```

How can we get started on proving no odd number can be abundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are odd abundant numbers. The first is $945$ and is in your list.

[OEIS: Odd abundant numbers](http://oeis.org/A005231)

Comment: Oh dear, I seemed to have overlooked this

Comment: Bonus point for not removing the question, even after 8 years! Made me chuckle.